# Unresolved external symbol "public: <function_name>"

Tags: c++, static, c++14, static-methods, unresolved-external

When i try to compile, i get this error:

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl
> A::FUNC_TEST(void)"

The header is as following:

```
#pragma once
class A
{    
public:
    static A global_var;

private:
    A();
    virtual ~A();
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;

public:
        static void FUNC_TEST();
};
```

while the source file is as following:

```
#include "A.hpp"
A A::global_var; 

A::A(){}

A::~A(){}

static void A::FUNC_TEST(){}
```

and the main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.hpp"

int main() {
    
    A::FUNC_TEST();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Im missing something basic..
So far i've searched for many similar questions, and most of them ended up by missing declaration of global_var, or access specifier for class name..

Would really appriciate your help.

EDIT:
cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Ex1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(Ex1 main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
static void A::FUNC_TEST(){}
```

Remove the `static` keyword from the definition in your `.cpp` file.

See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Edit:

As mentioned in comments, the issue was `A.cpp` not being included with `cmake`.

It should be `add_executable(Ex1 main.cpp A.cpp)`

Comment: @meowi how are you building your main program, is `A.cpp` not getting included.

Comment: it is indeed set in the cmake file (other, non-static functions are working just fine)

Comment: @meowi The example you've given at the moment isn't reproducible for me. Can you edit your post to add the `CMakeLists.txt` file you use for the above demo. As your issue could be related to your cmake setup

Comment: added the cmake file (thank you for trying helping me so hard)

Comment: wow that was the problem- didnt include the source files in the cmake... awful rookie mistake